# Importing users from CSV into AD with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm using the following script in order to import 100,000 users from a CSV file into Active Directory. However, I'm getting a lot of errors and need your help in eliminating them.

Script:

```
Import-Csv C:\csv\100Kusers.csv | ForEach-Object {
 $userPrinc = $_."Logon Username" + "@mydomain.com"
 New-QADUser -Name $_.Name `
 -ParentContainer $_."Container" `
 -SamAccountName $_."Logon Username" `
 -UserPassword "passw0rd123" `
 -FirstName $_.FirstName `
 -LastName $_."LastName" `
 -Description $_."Department" `
 -UserPrincipalName $userPrinc `
 -DisplayName $_."Name" `
 -StreetAddress $_."StreetAddress" `
 -City $_."City" `
 -State $_."State" `
 -PostalCode $_."PostalCode" `
 -Email $_."Email" `
 -Company $_."Company" `
 -Department $_."Department" `
 -HomePhone $_."HomePhone" `
 -Title $_."Title" `
 -Manager $_."Manager" ;`
 Add-QADGroupMember -identity $_."Group" -Member $_."Logon Username" ;`
 }
```

And here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Add-QADGroupMember : Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'jm?lmhx4'.
At C:\csv\PS_import_script.ps1:22 char:2
+  Add-QADGroupMember -identity $_."Group" -Member $_."Logon Username" ;`
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-QADGroupMember], ObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.DirectoryAccess.ObjectNotFoundException,Qu 
   est.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Commands.AddGroupMemberCmdlet2

    New-QADUser : A device attached to the system is not functioning.
At C:\csv\PS_import_script.ps1:3 char:2
+  New-QADUser -Name $_.Name `
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-QADUser], DirectoryServicesCOMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.NewUserCmdlet
```

CSV looks like this:

```
FirstName   Surname Name    StreetAddress   City    State   PostalCode  EmailAddress    Company Department  Group   HomePhone   Title   Manager Logon Username  Container
Jose    Mullane Jose Mul    Rue de Li?ge 493    Lompret WLX 6463    JoseLMullane@superrito.com  rmit    QA  QA-FL   0495 94 79 62   Laboratory animal technologist  tgatesjr    jmuljhk2    dcui.mydomain.com/dcui_OU/Finland/Departments/QA
```

Sorry, can't add more - formatting goes crazy when I copy a plain CSV into the post window.

Comment: The first one is pretty obvious: `jm?lmhx4` is not a valid group name

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I thought that Add-QADGroupMember -identity $_."Group" -Member $_."Logon Username" ;` should look for column Group in the CSV and then assign the user to the corresponding Group in AD. What I'm missing?

Comment: My humble google research tells me that "New-QADUser : A device attached to the system is not functioning." can occure when SamAccountName is CSV is longer than 20characters, but it's not in my case.

Comment: Depends on what is in your CSV file - can you provide a sample, like the first 20 rows?

Comment: added CSV example to my question

Comment: Seems like you might [need to specify `-Encoding` with Import-CSV](http://blogs.technet.com/b/samdrey/archive/2014/03/26/determine-the-file-encoding-of-a-file-csv-file-with-french-accents-or-other-exotic-characters-that-you-re-trying-to-import-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Definitely an encoding problem, but it's not clear if the CSV file might need to be regenerated with the proper encoding.  Note the street address of `Rue de Li?ge 493`.  If that's from the CSV, then the CSV was not Unicode encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks everyone. I agree that this could be an encoding issue and yes, the CSV itself had all those off "?" marks, after I saved it from xlsx format. We ended up using Pyhthon, which also was much faster, comparing to Pshell.

Yours,